# How to start the XCode 6 debugger before an exception is raised in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, exception, xcode6

In VisualStudio one can set the debugger to automatically break just *before* an exception is raised. This way it is extremely comfortable to inspect the context of the exception.
Is there a similar setting in XCode 6 for Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Add Exception Breakpoint` menu!

[image]

[image]

[image]